# C++ - work with file (read file) then show in the console

Tags: c++

I would like to read the content from the text file by C++ , I wrote the code as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    ifstream input("C:\\Users\\thang\\Desktop\\Thang\\output.txt");
    string str;
    while(!input.eof()) //check if it goes to the end of the file
    { 
        //getline(input,str); //
        input>>str; // get the value of str from the file 
        cout<<str<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it just show me the result with no empty row , but the output.txt file has the empty line.
I have attached the screenshot
[image: the result]

[image: my file]

Could you please help explain why it get the result without the empty line ? Appriciated for all assist.

Comment: Not related to the main problem, your usage of `while(!input.eof())` is [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: Thank you , Could you please advise some alternative for my case ? I thought this for checking if it goes to the end of the input file in my case.

Comment: Check if reading succeeded *before* trying to use what are read like `while(input>>str)` or `while(getline(input,str))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the [`operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) to read `std::string` from `std::ifstream` skips leading whitespaces. Newline characters is one kind of whitespace characters, so they are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Because `input>>str` strips away any leading whitespace.

If you just need to read the file like `cat` does, use `rdbuf` directly:

```cpp
ifstream input(...);
std::cout<<input.rdbuf()<<std::endl;
```

If you want to iterate over the lines, including the empty ones, use `std::getline`

```cpp
ifstream input(...);
for (std::string line; std::getline(input, line); )
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have changed the code by using getline(input,str) ,then std::cout , it could work fine.